# Outlook Addin: Jumplists && only one addin instance even with multiple outlook instances

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin

Outlook Addin written in C#, Visual Studio 2012.
3 questions:

1. I have a form window in my outlook addin, it takes it's own space in the taskbar. A right click on it reveals the Outlook jumplist. I would like to customize the jumplist of only my addin taskbar entry.
   If that's not possible then manipulating the Outlook jumplist would be the alternative.
   How do I do it?
2. How do I make sure that the addin outlook on startup operations only happen when starting the first Outlook instance? I could realize that via registry or a hidden file but that doesn't seem satisfying.
3. Additionally I would like to hand over the addin object instances to one of the remaining Outlook instances if the first one is closed.
   Or at least let the remaining instances realize that the first one got closed so they can build up the addin functionality again.
   I have no idea at all how to do that. Is there any object accessible via my c# code that all Outlook instances interact with to let them communicate?

Answer (score 0):

1. What jumplist are you referring too? How do you want to customize it?
2. & 3. Only one Outlook.exe instance should be running at once. When a new Outlook window opens, it adds to the Application.Explorers collection

Comment: 1. The jumplist of the form window I created. If that isn't possible it's fine to edit the Outlook jumplist. 2. Yeah, I saw that, this is solved then.

Comment: What is the Outlook "jumplist" you are referring to? A Folder Picker??

Comment: Jumplist as in "context menu that opens when you right click on the taskbaritem". The jumplist default for Outlook lets you write a new mail for example. I would like to pupulate my own taskbar item with custom options or insert them in them in the Outlook taskbar item.

Comment: Oh, THAT jumplist! :-) Yeah, I'm not sure about that one - check the Windows SDK as that's not handled by the Outlook Object Model